# Maya, PYTHON: how do i select all but one in a list?

Tags: python, list, maya, deselect

## how do i deselect all objects except for my last selection?

When I'm working with 2 objects there's no problem because all i have to do is toggle list[0] which would be first object that i selected (this is how i have it working below).

```
import maya.cmds as mc
sel_objs = mc.ls(sl = True)
mc.select(sel_objs[0], tgl = True)
```

thanks

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham. im sorry im new to programming. could you let me in on where exactly [:-1]  is in the list or what it means?

Comment: it means all objects in the list except the last i.e `[1,2,3][:-1] == [1,2]`

Comment: Does that mean [:+1] is everything except first?

Comment: `[1:]` means all but the first, from index 1 to the end

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what i was looking for. i'm going to play around with this a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the selection entirely with the last element of the list:

```
mc.select(sel_objs[-1], replace=True)
```

`replace` is the equivalent to clicking on it rather than ctrl-clicking or shift-clicking. The selection is cleared in the action of selecting the new object.

`sel_objs[-1]` returns the last object in the list, just as `sel_objs[0]` returns the first object.